# How can I create a Drupal/IFTTT trigger or action?

Tags: 7, actions, rules

I am looking into the service [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com/wtf) ("IF This Then That"), which is like a trigger/action for the internet. For example, I could tell it that IF I post a new image to flikr, THEN post a link to it on Facebook.

I am wondering if anyone has managed to integrate this into drupal, so, for example, I could automatically post across social media networks when I create new content on a drupal site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module for that.
[Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) and/or [Gigya](https://drupal.org/project/gigya)

probably more around.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a service like [ping.fm](http://ping.fm) to post media to multiple sites. There is a [ping.fm](http://drupal.org/project/pingfm) Drupal module available.

Comment: Update : Seesmic has been acquired by HootSuite and as of March 2013, the Seesmic website is no longer supported ...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here - a quick implementation of rules action and IFTTT maker. https://www.drupal.org/node/2753119 - https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/ursuvictor/2753083. 
Simply create a new rule(ie: User logs in) , for actions select IFTTT, fill in the IFTTT key (https://ifttt.com/maker), the event name, and the three variables (you can use tokens) to send over to IFTTT if you want to send any, then Enjoy. I am sending my user logins to a google spreadsheet, sending a slack message on user register, and turning off the light when my personal user logs out from the website.